# Cannot install fortran program on macOS via Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, fortran, gfortran

When I run `make` in the Terminal I get the following error:

```
    gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘15.6.0 
    gfortran  -O1  -I..    -DFLUSH  -c ../aocn2.f90
```

Any ideas on how to install fortran for macOS?

Comment: Have you installed the xcode command line tools? xcode-select --install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO, the easiest way to install **Fortran** under **macOS/OSX** is via **homebrew**.

First, go to **App Store** and install Apple's `Xcode`. You can get to **App Store** by typing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and starting to type `App Store` and then hit `Enter/Return` once it guesses correctly. **Xcode** looks like this:

[image]

Then start a Terminal, using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> Terminal `Enter/Return` and do the rest in Terminal.

Install the *"Xcode command line tools"*:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then install **homebrew** by going to [homebrew website](https://brew.sh) and copying and pasting the one-liner there.

Then install GCC (*"GNU Compiler Collection"*) which includes `gfortran`:

```
brew install gcc
```

You will need to set your `PATH` to include `/usr/local/bin` which is where **homebrew** installs programs:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

You can now run:

```
gfortran someFile.for
```